# C# : hide the file security tab

Tags: c#, tabs, access-control, taskbar

i am working on application that deals with file and folders security and i am good so far i use that function to deny access to certain files ,

```
                DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);

                foreach (FileInfo filesindires in dir.GetFiles())
                {
                    FileSecurity ds = filesindires.GetAccessControl();
                    ds.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("Authenticated Users", FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Deny));
                    filesindires.SetAccessControl(ds);
                }
```

but i`d like to add more security by hiding the Security tab or even disabling the Advanced security option in security tab , if this is possible could you provide me with some code or even the way how to disable the tab so i can figure the code my self , even though i like the solution with code :D

Comment: Who is the attacker in your threat model? What abilities/tools can he have?

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved but will affect folders, files, shortcuts, and drives for all users on the computer. If you still want to do this, let me know on a comment.

1. Open your Local Group Policy Editor (C:\Windows\System32\gpedit.msc) note: not all versions of windows have this.
2. Go To User Configuration > Admisnitrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Explorer
3. Click on Remove Security tab and on the new window select Disabled and click OK.

That should do it.

Comment: ok i`d like to know it ,even if i wont use it , at least i learn something new and thanks a lot for your help .

Answer (score 0):

That is actually a function of Windows Explorer, the best approach would have to come through group policy management.